# How can show JSON array data in dropdown list in asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, drop-down-menu

I want to populate JSON array data in a dropdown list in asp.net. My json Array is,

```
"Product": [
            {
                "id": 0,
                "productId": 0,
                "quantity": 20,
                "productName": "Rawai",
                "brandName": "Kamal Products",
                "productCode": 0,
                "brandId": 0,
                "productPrice": 0
            },
  {
                "id": 0,
                "productId": 0,
                "quantity": 22,
                "productName": "OIL",
                "brandName": "Kamal Proucts",
                "productCode": 0,
                "brandId": 0,
                "productPrice": 0
            },
 {
                "id": 0,
                "productId": 0,
                "quantity": 3,
                "productName": "Ghee",
                "brandName": "Kamal Products",
                "productCode": 0,
                "brandId": 0,
                "productPrice": 0
            }

        ]
```

I am getting URLand from URL I get JSON array
    Product lstProduct = new Product();
                List lstBrandProduct = new List();

```
            string urls = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(urlnames);
            JArray jsonArrays = JArray.Parse(urls);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArrays.Count; i++)
            {
                CustomerOrder isiData = (new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize<CustomerOrder>(jsonArrays[i].ToString());

                for (int j = 0; j < isiData.product.Count; j++)
                {
                    drpListBrand.DataTextField = isiData.product[j].BrandName;
                }
            }
```

I want to show the 'product Name' in the dropdown list how can I show?

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Did you try searching how to parse JSON? What problem did you encounter? If you haven't tried anything, what is the question?

Comment: Posted question does not show effort to research or describe a specific problem. Too broad.

Comment: I was added drop down list control in asp.net page,    `<asp:DropDownList ID="drpListBrand" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>` and for that I was write code in c# to call JSON array

Comment: You should deserialize it to CLR objects and add those to your list.

Comment: I was updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use NewtonSoft.JSON Nuget

```
var files = JObject.Parse(YourJson);
var recList = files.SelectTokens("$").ToList();
  foreach (JProperty item in recList.Children())
  {
     var key = item.Name.ToString(); //store the root item
     var value= item.Value.ToString();
     var breakitem = item.Values().ToList();
     for (int i = 0; i < breakitem.Count; i++)
     {
      string drpvalue = breakitem[i]["productName"].ToString();
      //ADD this value to your dropdownList Object
     }     
   }
```

Comment: But my JSon is different than that json, its array in array json means its nested Json array

Comment: You can use JArray.Parse instead of JObject then or paste the complete array here in question ?